# Converting.FromBase64String is throwing a Format Exception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, encryption, base64

I am trying to check if a username is a base64 string. It kept throwing an illegal exception error message even though the string is a base64 encoded.  What am I missing here?

```
public bool checkBase64String(string value) //value = “TWrXfr4gGTE%3d”
       {
            try
            {
                byte[] vArray = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
                return true;
            }
            catch (FormatException ex)
            {
                ex.ToString();
            }
            return false;
        }
```

The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The input is URL encoded and the trailing `=` became `%3d`. It needs to be decoded to `TWrXfr4gGTE=` before converting...

Fiddle... http://dotnetfiddle.net/S8UpdJ